# Highlight the Activated Button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

I have a wpf form that is called by a static method in much the same way as `MessageBox.Show()`; the button layout is defined in the method, and can be customised, within certain parameters. Each button is added with a style that is `BasedOn` a central style.

Part of this style is a trigger that highlights the default button, so the user knows what will happen if they press `enter`. However, if the user presses tab a few times, there is a little dotted border that moves into each of the buttons in turn and then *this* is the button they will get when they press enter. I would like my highlight to start on the default button but follow this... ?focus? around if the user chooses to tab between the buttons.

I had thought that the property to trigger on in the `<ControlTemple.Triggers>` would be `IsFocused`, but this does not seem to behave as I expected - here is a snippet of my xaml code as it stands:

```
<!--....-->
   <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border x:Name="border" 
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        Padding="0" 
                        BorderBrush="WhiteSmoke" 
                        CornerRadius="2" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Contents" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform" TargetName="Contents">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="2"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefault" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="border" Value="3"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="IsDefault" Value="True"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="IsDefault" Value="False"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
<!--....-->
```

I thought that the focus would set the default when it triggered, and this would cause the highlight (3px white border) to show as the user pressed tab.

What is the property that changes when the user presses tab (and/or why is it not responding for me?)

-------------- ************ EDIT ************-------------

Attempting to add lines to the code behind to add triggers directly. The foreach loop tracks through a list of custom class items that are basically slightly modified buttons; the `b.Style` is of type Style, but is looked up from some resources

```
        foreach (Buttons b in buttonList)
        {
            if (i > 0)
            {
                totalWidthNeeded = totalWidthNeeded + gapPixels;
                ColumnDefinition gapColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
                gapColumn.Width = gapWidth;
                ButtonRowGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(gapColumn);
                i++;
            }

            Button thisButton = new Button();

            var setter = new Setter() { Property = Button.IsDefaultProperty, Value = true};
            var trigger = new Trigger() { Property = Button.IsFocusedProperty, Value=true, Setters = { setter } };

            b.Style.Triggers.Add(trigger);

            thisButton.Style = b.Style;
```

Sadly, this code does not make a trigger that has a visible effect from the IsDefault trigger shown in the xaml above (I have removed the two IsFocused triggers).

Comment: Focus the actual Button that the style/template is applied to. You can't do this in the style/template itself.

Comment: ah! That makes sense; so add the focus change bit to the button in the code behind after the `Button thisButton = new Button();` adds each button to the form?

Comment: I have edited the question to include a snippet of code behind - trying not to include vast swathes of code - hopefully it is enough to see my interpretation of your comments so far... although I haven't got it working, so must have missed something!

Comment: What exaclty are you trying to do with the Button?

Comment: make the button which will be "pressed" if the user pressed enter appear different to all the other buttons, even if the user tabs around to change the button from the default.

Comment: So you basically want the currently focused Button to look different?

Comment: yes - ideally that would extend to say if none are focussed, the default will look different. I think I have got too into triggers, and should be looking instead at a new routed event handler or two... GotFocus,LostFocus etc...?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you want but from my understanding you need:

1. Highlight default button
2. When used tab-out existing button to next one highlight currently selected button

Based on my understanding I've created an example which may help you out:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsDefault" Value="True" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=btnDefault}">
    <Button>Button 1</Button>
    <Button>Button 2</Button>
    <Button x:Name="btnDefault">Button 3</Button>
    <Button>Button 4</Button>
    <Button>Button 5</Button>
    <Button>Button 6</Button>
    <Button>Button 7</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Apologies for my lack of clarity; I lack the understanding to sufficiently express my own requirements - just enough knowledge to confuse me! So the problem with my version was that the trigger was on the controltemplate, not the style itself?